# insert objects in NSArray with NSDictionary

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary

I try to create a NSArray of objects using data from a NSArray. So, I try to replicate the insertion of objects below automatically

Here is the starting position

```
    candyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"chocolate" name:@"chocolate bar"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"chocolate" name:@"chocolate chip"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"chocolate" name:@"dark chocolate"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"hard" name:@"lollipop"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"hard" name:@"candy cane"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"hard" name:@"jaw breaker"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"caramel"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"sour chew"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"peanut butter cup"],
                  [Candy candyOfCategory:@"other" name:@"gummi bear"], nil];
```

Here is my attempt to automate

```
NSArray *entries = [feed objectForKey:@"bookmarks"];

NSMutableArray *nameInsert;

for (NSDictionary *item in entries)
{
    [nameInsert addObject: [Candy candyOfCategory:@"chocolate" name:[item objectForKey:@"name"]]];
}

candyArray = nameInsert;
```

Why nameInsert contains nothing while entries's data has two inputs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the `nameInsert` array.

Replace

```
NSMutableArray *nameInsert;
```

with

```
NSMutableArray *nameInsert = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:entries.count];
```